# Error en peticion JSON por jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Tengo una peticion ajax y no consigo tener acceso a los datos, un JSON.
Esta es la peticion:

```
$.ajax({
 url: url,
 dataType: 'json',
 crossOrigin: true,
 xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
 success: function(data) { alert('ok'); },
 error: function (data){alert(JSON.stringify(data));} 
});
```

Y esta es la respuesta que veo mediante F12 en la consola de debug de firefox, en la cual sale una linea indicando XHR seguido de la peticion GET.
Al desplegar esa linea puedo ver "Cabeceras","Cookies","Parametros","Respuesta","Tiempos","Traza de la Pila".

En la pestaña de Cabeceras obtengo lo siguiente:
  XHR GET http://MyServer.com/?loadsettings
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

URL solicitada:http://MyServer.com/?loadsettings
Método de la petición:GET
Dirección remota:MyServer.com:80
Código de estado: 200
Versión:HTTP/1.1

Cabeceras de la respuesta (83 B)
Content-Length
159
Content-Type
html
Server
Mongoose/6.16

Cabeceras de la petición (426 B)
Accept
application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Authorization
Basic aW5ub22hdGljUmlubm7tYXRtYw==
Cache-Control
no-cache
Connection
keep-alive
DNT 
1
Host
MyServer.com
Origin
null
Pragma
no-cache
User-Agent
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0

Y en la pestaña Respuesta tengo el JSON que estoy pidiendo.
Esta es la respuesta copiada de la consola de debug del navegador:

JSON
Dato1   Valor1
Dato2   Valor2
Dato3   Valor3
Dato4   Valor4
Dato5   Valor5
Dato6   Valor6
Dato7   Valor7

Contenido de respuesta
{
"Dato1":"Valor1",
"Dato2":"Valor2",
"Dato3":"Valor3",
"Dato4":"Valor4",
"Dato5":"Valor5",
"Dato6":"Valor6",
"Dato7":"Valor7"
}

El caso es que la peticion ajax, devuelve error (
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
) y no tengo acceso al JSON.

Comment: ¿ Están **exactamente** copiadas las cabeceras que obtienes ? Esas cabecerar que muestras son erróneas.

Comment: En cualquier caso, el problema está en el servidor. Fíjate que dice `Content-Type: html`. **No** estás recibiendo un JSON, o esa cabecera está mal puesta en el servidor.

Comment: Estan copiadas directamente del navegador.

Comment: Pero parece que hay una respuesta, ¿o qué significa `Contenido de respuesta`? ¿El código no entra en el `alert` del `success`?

Comment: @A.Cedano Efectivamente, la respuesta la puedo copiar de la consola de depuracion que ofrece firefox, pero la funcion entra en alert de error.

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes `crossOrigin: true,`? Parece que la petición es en el mismo servidor ¿no? Y, por qué tienes `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },` ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano si no pongo esa linea "xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }," el servidor no responde nada. La peticion no es desde el servidor, el servidor esta en otra ip de la red interna.

Comment: Es muy rato que responda los datos y responda error también. Sugiero que revises el log de errores del servidor a ver si hay algo allí.